# How to create a condition in jquery onchange event?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, codeigniter

I just need your help about my problem and sorry for my question problem I just don't know how to title my question. Hope you understand my problem. Now here it is.

By the way I am creating a **Purchase Order form.**

I created a **table form** that consist of textboxes, selection and some buttons. The scenario is. I have a selection box that contains my supplier names. And after the selection was made. An **auto filter** will be activated. Filling all the supplier's information/detail. Such as address, contact number, **tin**, etc...

Below the supplier's information I have a rows for inserting orders.
The first columns is for Item Code second is quantity and third is price and last price is total. Below the table I have a textboxes that will compute the grand total, vat, discount, etc etc...

Now here's the part that I don't know how to do. 
After the supplier selection, the jquery must detect if there's a value in the **tin** textbox. In displaying value automatically I don't have a problem for that. But my real problem is in the computation side. Because as I have said earlier below the table is the computation for **vat**. The **computation for vat** must be **triggered** if the **tin textbox is not empty**. Meaning if the tin textbox is not empty the computation for VAT should be enable. If empty, the jquery should skip this part.

Here's my sample code:

**jquery part**

```
    //automatic computation in rows
    $('[id^=qty],[id^=price]').on('change',function() {

        var index = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0];
        var qty = parseInt($('#qty'+index).val());
        var price = parseFloat($('#price'+index).val());
        var total = 0;

        $('#total'+index).val((qty * price ? qty * price : 0).toFixed(2));

        var total = 0;
        $('[id^=total]').each(function(index){
            total+=parseFloat($(this).val()?$(this).val():0);
        });
        $('#sum_of_total').val(total.toFixed(2));

        //NOW HERE'S THE COMPUTATION FOR VAT THAT SHOULD SKIP IF THE TIN IS EMPTY
        var vatable = total / 1.12;
        var vatable_amt = vatable * 0.12;
        var totalVat = vatable + vatable_amt;

        $('#vatable').val(vatable.toFixed(2)); 
        $("#vatable_amount").val(vatable_amt.toFixed(2));
        $("#gtotal").val(totalVat.toFixed(2));
        //END OF COMPUTATION
    });

    //HERE'S THE AUTO ASSIGN OF VALUES
    //AUTO ASSIGN TO SUPPLIER INFO
    $('#supplier_list').bind('change', function(){
        var var_add_category ='<?php echo site_url("purchaseorder_controller/supplier_details"); ?>';
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url: var_add_category,
            data:{ id: $(this).val() },
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(d){

                var bankname = d['bankname'];
                var bankbranch = d['bankbranch'];

                $("[name=spaddress]").val(d['spaddr']);
                $("[name=tin]").val(d['sptinno']);
                $("[name=contactperson]").val(d['pricontactname']);
                $("[name=contactnumber]").val(d['sptelno']);
                $("[name=bank]").val(bankname + ' - ' + bankbranch);
                $("[name=account_name]").val(d['bankacctname']);
                $("[name=account_no]").val(d['bankacctno']);

            }
        });    
    });
```

Here's the **HTML/PHP part:**

```
Here's the supplier entry, it will trigger to add information in the supplier fields

<select id="supplier_list" style="width: 100%;" name="supplier_id" required="required">
    <option value="">--Choose Supplier--</option>
      <?php
         foreach($resultSelectSupplier->result_array() as $suppliers){
           echo "<option value=".$suppliers['spid'].">".$suppliers['spname']."</option>";
         }
      ?>
</select>
.
.
.
//The TIN textbox that need to validate if empty or not(used for computation in VAT)
 <td>
      <label>TIN #</label>
 </td>
 <td>
      <input type="text" class="k-textbox" name="tin" maxlength="11" id="tin_number" />
 </td>
```

**Here's the PHP part for looping the rows for adding order item**

```
 <?php

    $sqlGetCode = "SELECT itemid,itemcode,itemname FROM items";
    $resultGetCode = $this->db->query($sqlGetCode);

    for($i = 1; $i < 16; $i++){

       echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>";
             echo "<select name='code[]' id='code{$i}' style='width:100'>";
                echo "<option value=''><label>--CHOOSE ITEMS--</label></option>";

                foreach($resultGetCode->result_array() as $list){
                   echo "<option value='".$list['itemid']."'>".$list['itemcode']." --- ".$list['itemname']."</option>";  
                }
             echo "</select>";
          echo "</td>";

          echo "<td><input type='text' name='qty[]' id='qty{$i}' style='text-align: center' value='' /></td>";
          echo "<td><input type='text' name='price[]' id='price{$i}' style='text-align: right;' value='' onblur='' /></td>";
          echo "<td><input type='text' name='total[]' id='total{$i}' style='font-family: courier; text-align: right; background-color: lightgray; color: red' readonly='readonly' value='' /></td>";
      echo "<tr>";

    }
```

?>

The finally the textbox to show the computed items

```
 <div align="right">
            <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>VATable Amount:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="vatable" id="vatable" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>VAT Input:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="vatable_amount" id="vatable_amount" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>TOTAL SALES:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" readonly="readonly" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="subtotal" id="gtotal" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>PURCHASE DISCOUNT:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="discount" id="discount" /></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>TOTAL AMOUNT DUE:</td>
                        <td><input type="text" class="k-textbox" value="0.00" style="color: red; text-align: right; font-family: courier" name="total_amt_due" id="total_amt_due" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <input type="hidden" id="sum_of_total" name="sum_of_total" />
            </table>
        </div>
```

Here's the formula for computation:

*Note: this computaion will be trigger IF the TIN textbox IS NOT EMPTY

```
VATABLE AMOUNT = SUM OF TOTAL / 1.12
VATABLE INPUT = VATABLE AMOUNT * 0.12
TOTAL SALES = VATABLE AMOUNT + VATABLE INPUT
```

*Note: this computation is fixed, if no TIN the SUM OF TOTAL is the default value for computing TOTAL AMOUNT DUE

```
Computation for total amount due:
PURCHASE DISCOUNT = The user will input any discount number here
TOTAL AMOUNT DUE = TOTAL SALES - PURCHASE DISCOUNT (should be trigger automatically)
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rochellecanale/dtfV4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a condition in your `onchange` event:

```
//NOW HERE'S THE COMPUTATION FOR VAT THAT SHOULD SKIP IF THE TIN IS EMPTY
var vatable = 0;
var vatable_amt = 0;
var totalVat = 0;

if($("#tin_number").val().length != 0)
{
    var vatable = total / 1.12;
    var vatable_amt = vatable * 0.12;
}
totalVat = vatable + vatable_amt;

$('#vatable').val(vatable.toFixed(2)); 
$("#vatable_amount").val(vatable_amt.toFixed(2));
$("#gtotal").val(totalVat.toFixed(2));
//END OF COMPUTATION
```

> Calculate VAT only when length of TIN No. is greater than 0. Ideally length should be equal to 10 and may also check if TIN No. is a number.

Comment: Ok thaks I will try that.